# What's the difference between 選び (erabi) and せんたくし (sentakushi)?

Tags: words

選び (erabi) and せんたくし (sentakushi) both relate to choice and selection, but I am not sure what the difference is?

Comment: If you were actually looking for the difference between 選ぶ and 選択する, see [here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14819/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those words mean ***very*** different things.

「選び」 means the act of choosing or just plain "choosing".  It is an ***action*** that humans perform.

Note: 「選び」 is most often used as a suffix rather than as an "independent" word.

Examples: 「大学選{だいがくえら}び」(selecting a college), 「ダンナ選び」(selecting a husband), etc.

「選択肢{せんたくし}」 refers to the actual choices available.  It is ***not*** an action.

> In short, 「選**び**」＝「選択」and not 「選択肢」

also:

> 「選**ぶ**」＝「選択する」 (Both verbs)

Answer (score 2):

選ぶ{えらぶ} is a verb which means 'to choose.'

選択肢{せんたくし} is a noun which means 'choices.'  (Assuming that is the kanji form of せんたくし that you were looking for.)